# Consulta ao banco de dados em C# mvc + Intity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando exibir o resultado da minha query na view. Porem o valor DESC_DESC_ORIGEM esta vindo vazio.

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Net;
using ControleTTM.EntityFramework;
using ControleTTM.Models;
using ControleTTM.Helper;
using ControleTTM.ViewModel;
using ControleTTM.Filters;

namespace ControleTTM.Controllers
{
[MyFirstCustomFilter]
public class ChamadoController : Controller
{
    private ModelCTTM db = new ModelCTTM();
    // GET: Chamado
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var resultado = (from a in db.NEW_CTTM_TICKETS_OPEN
                       join b in db.NEW_CTTM_ORIGIN_PRIORITY
                       on a.ID_ORIGIN equals b.ID_ORIGIN
                       select new
                       {
                           CTTM_CHAMADO_ID = a.CTTM_CHAMADO_ID,
                           SYSTEM_STATUS_ID = a.SYSTEM_STATUS_ID,
                           ID_SISTEMA_ORIGEM = a.ID_SISTEMA_ORIGEM,
                           CODIGO = a.CODIGO,
                           IDADE = a.IDADE,
                           IDADE_CASO = a.IDADE_CASO,
                           TELEFONE_PRINCIPAL = a.TELEFONE_PRINCIPAL,
                           ID_ORIGIN = a.ID_ORIGIN,
                           DT_CRIACAO = a.DT_CRIACAO,
                           STATUS = a.STATUS,
                           SEVERIDADE = a.SEVERIDADE,
                           RAZAO_SOCIAL = a.RAZAO_SOCIAL,
                           SEGMENTO = a.SEGMENTO,
                           ORGANIZACAO = a.ORGANIZACAO,
                           ID_TITLE = a.ID_TITLE,
                           PLANO = a.PLANO,
                           TELEFONE_ALTERNATIVO = a.TELEFONE_ALTERNATIVO,
                           CPF = a.CPF,
                           CNPJ = a.CNPJ,
                           HISTORICO = a.HISTORICO,
                           NOTAS = a.NOTAS,
                           NE_ID = a.NE_ID,
                           ORIGIN_LEVEL = a.ORIGIN_LEVEL,
                           ID_SLA = a.ID_SLA,
                           SLA_LEVEL = a.SLA_LEVEL,
                           ID_TYPE = a.ID_TYPE,
                           PENDING = a.PENDING,
                           FG_TRATAMENTO = a.FG_TRATAMENTO,
                           DESC_ORIGEM = b.DESC_ORIGIN

                       }).ToList();
        return View(resultado);
    }
}
}
```

MODEL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ControleTTM.EMPresets;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ControleTTM.EntityFramework;

namespace ControleTTM.Models
{

public class Chamado
{
    public string CN { get; set; }

    public string GSM { get; set; }


    public virtual string DESC_ORIGEM { get; set; }

    public EntityFramework.ModelCTTM model { get; set; }

    //public virtual EntityFramework.NEW_CTTM_ORIGIN_PRIORITY NEW_CTTM_ORIGIN_PRIORITYS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityFramework.NEW_CTTM_ORIGIN_PRIORITY> NEW_CTTM_ORIGIN_PRIORITYS { get; set; }

    public string CTTM_CHAMADO_ID { get; set; }
    public string SYSTEM_STATUS_ID { get; set; }
    public string ID_SISTEMA_ORIGEM { get; set; }
    public string CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string IDADE { get; set; }
    public string IDADE_CASO { get; set; }
    public string TELEFONE_PRINCIPAL { get; set; }
    public string ID_ORIGIN { get; set; }
    public string DT_CRIACAO { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string SEVERIDADE { get; set; }
    public string RAZAO_SOCIAL { get; set; }
    public string SEGMENTO { get; set; }
    public string ORGANIZACAO { get; set; }
    public string ID_TITLE { get; set; }
    public string PLANO { get; set; }
    public string TELEFONE_ALTERNATIVO { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string HISTORICO { get; set; }
    public string NOTAS { get; set; }
    public string NE_ID { get; set; }
    public string ORIGIN_LEVEL { get; set; }
    public string ID_SLA { get; set; }
    public string SLA_LEVEL { get; set; }
    public string ID_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string PENDING { get; set; }
    public string FG_TRATAMENTO { get; set; }



    public Chamado()
    {

    }
}
}
```

VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<ControleTTM.Models.Chamado>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="row">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chamados').DataTable();
    });</script>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Tratar", "Tickets")'" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-width">
        Tratar Chamado
    </button>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-width">
        Assigned

        <span class="label label-primary custom-badge">42</span>
    </button>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-width">
        Working

        <span class="label label-primary custom-badge">10</span>
    </button>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-width">
        Pending

        <span class="label label-primary custom-badge">5</span>
    </button>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-width">
        Total

        <span class="label label-primary custom-badge">100</span>
    </button>

</div>

</div>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="chamados">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CODIGO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDADE)
        </th>           
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESC_ORIGEM)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_TITLE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID_SLA)
        </th>

    </tr>

</thead>


<tbody>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CODIGO)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDADE)
            </td>                
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESC_ORIGEM)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_TITLE)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_SLA)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

Comment: Não consegui entender a pergunta, você quer saber o porquê de estar vazio ou de não mostrar na view?

Comment: Quero saber o pq de esta vazio e não esta mostrando na view. Onde estou errando

Comment: seu problema parece ser simples, segue uma lista do que você pode fazer pra conferir: 1- Verificar se o campo está vazio no banco, 2- Verificar se a lista da consulta possui o item preenchido, 3- Tentar alimentar o DisplayFor com outros parâmetros, para tratar caso seja vazio.

Comment: 1 . OK - campo não esta vazio no banco 2. Não entendi.  3. Ok funcionando.

Comment: pelo que vi, esse campo é o unico da tabela nomeada B. você já colocou um breakpoint na linha return View(resultado); da Controller pra ver se o resultado está trazendo esse campo?

Comment: Na sua model...  `public virtual string DESC_ORIGEM { get; set; }` e na sua controller você está retornando uma `List<object>` não uma `List<Chamado>();`

Comment: Não entendi.. oq eu deveria fazer para solucionar?